# How to create a matrix where I can distribute the Values to specific column headers?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Specifically, this is the table I have:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o9I5.png)
I would like to create a Matrix in Power BI Desktop that would look something like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xPBN.png)
Regarding the months, I would see them appear under each indicator, wheather it had allocated a number in the respectvie month.

When I add the **AB Plan** for example, it shows me also under the **222**, but I want it to be shown under the **111** only. And **CD Plan** under **222** only.

Could you please suggest me what would be the necessary steps I should follow?
Thank you very much.